# How to show keyboard automatically when searchController is presented

Tags: ios, swift, button, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

```
@IBAction func MapSearchController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let searchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchTableViewController") as! SearchTableViewController

        mapSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchTable)
        mapSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchTable
        present(mapSearchController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        mapSearchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        self.mapSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        self.mapSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.mapSearchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        self.mapSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "חפש ברים"
        self.mapSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
        mapSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchTable.mapView = mapView
        searchTable.handleMapSearchDelegate = self
```

How to show keyboard automatically when searchController is presented? i tried a lot of solutions but none of them worked for me ..including `becomeFirstResponder()` and such... please help

Comment: set it as first responder

Comment: already did ... doesn't work for me...

Comment: Same problem here. Tried all the solutions out there, including the one mentioned below. Not working. Xcode 9, iOS11. On simulator and on devices.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is Search controller is not presented when view id loaded so even after making becomeFirstResponder doesn't solve the issue. Below code will fix the issue and open the keyboard with cursor in searchbar.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, move:

```
present(mapSearchController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to the end, after you are finished settings all the properties on mapSearchController.

Then make sure you add the delegate method:

```
func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
  searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder = true
}
```

If that still doesn't work, make sure this VC conforms to the search UISearchControllerDelegate.

Comment: In what way did it not work? Was didPresentSearchController triggered?

Comment: idk ... how can i check if it triggered... on my device the keyboard doesn't show up ... i have to press the search bar for it to show up

Comment: first move making app crash saying `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Answer (score 0):

You're setting it too early. At that moment the the `viewDidLoad` of the your `MapSearchController` instance hasn't been triggered yet. You can only `becomeFirstResponder` after `viewDidLoad`.

So what you have to do is: set the `becomeFirstResponder` in the `viewDidAppear` of `MapSearchController`.